# Need to pick a random coordinate from a two dimensional vector

Tags: c++, vector

This is my first ever post, so I'm sorry if I'm doing something wrong.

What I'm having trouble is picking a coordinate from a two dimensional vector. 
Here's how my code looks like:

Let's assume that allMoves is a two dimentional coordinate vector.

```
int vectorSize = allMoves.size();
int r = rand() % vectorSize;
vector<Coordinate> finalList = allAiMoves[r]; // error here

int finalListSize = finalList.size();
int t = rand() % finalListSize;
```

What i'm trying to accomplish is first pick a random vector within the vectors. then apply that vector to a new vector and then pick a random element from there. however my code gives me an error at the specified place.

Comment: What error is shown specifically? Out of bounds access? Ideally [edit] your question and provide us with a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Make a [mcve] to get better answers. You need to at least tell us which error happened so we know you didn't just mistype `allAiMoves` when you meant `allMoves`.

Comment: Yes, I meant allMoves.

I forgot to mention I'm using Qt. also the error i'm getting is the following:
conversion from '___gnu_cxx::__aloc_traits<std::allocator<Coordinate> > :: value_type{aka Coordinate}' to non-scalar type ' std::vector<Coordinate>' requested

Comment: @Arcana You can edit your original answer to include this information. The error you are getting indicates that that value on the right hand side is a `Coordinate`, not a `vector<Coordinate>`.

Comment: Like two people already wrote before, provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example. We have no idea what allMoves is. Also, use the edit Button if allAiMoves should be allMoves. Since this changes the outcome, nobody else will edit your question in that way and newcomers will start by assuming that this might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The integer `r` refers to the vector `allMoves`. Therefore the 3rd line of your code snippet should read:

```
vector<Coordinate> finalList = allMoves[r];
```

You seem to have a compilation error. You could have look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717533/c-vector-of-vectors#2717552) where you can find an example of a vector of a vector.

Comment: Right. I just wrote it incorrectly. It's allMoves either way.